# How to compute efficiently an orthogonality vector ? (NLP)

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

this is my first question here so I am sorry if I am not doing this right.

So, I have a problem computing an orthogonality matrix. I mean, I want to compute an array, similar to co-occurrence matrix, but not having co-occurrences: I want occurrences alone. The array has to be of size *(number of words, number of words)*, and I am fully aware that this array will be very sparse.

The problem begins with the fact that the 'count' function has to differenciate words on the right and words on the left of the target within a window of 5 words: this is problem number 1. How to do this efficiently ? Here is my code for that :
*brokensentence is how I named my tokenized text*

```
import collections 
def contextDefiner(word,brokensentence,side):
    brokensentence = np.array(brokensentence)
    count = collections.Counter()
    if side == 'right':
        context = [[b,c,d,e,f] for (a,b,c,d,e,f) in  
                   zip(brokensentence[:],brokensentence[1:],brokensentence[2:],brokensentence[3:],brokensentence[4:],brokensentence[5:]) if a==word]  
    if side == 'left':
        context = [[a,b,c,d,e] for (a,b,c,d,e,f) in 
                   zip(brokensentence[:],brokensentence[1:],brokensentence[2:],brokensentence[3:],brokensentence[4:],brokensentence[5:]) if f==word]
    for ngram in context:
        count.update(ngram)
    return (count)
```

OK, now, my second problem with this is that my output is a dictionary. I have to define the context for each word in my vocabulary. This is how I defined my vocabulary :

```
def vocabularyCreator(corpus):
    vocabulary = sorted(set(wordBreaker(corpus)))
    count=0
    dictionary={}
    for word in vocabulary:
         dictionary[word]=count
         count+=1
    return dictionary
```

Now, I have to translate the results for each word into an array. Keep in mind that the indexes of my array have to be the same indexes in my vocabulary. I mean, if the word "bear" is the 23rd word in my vocabulary, the context has to be stored in the 23rd row. This is what I did, but it takes SO LONG to compute !

```
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix

def matrixFiller(vocab,brokensentence,side):
    words = vocab.keys()
    matrix = lil_matrix((len(vocab),len(vocab)))
    for word in words:
        wordindex = vocab.get(word)
        context = contextDefiner(word,brokensentence,side)
        for item in context:
            itemindex = vocab.get(item)
            matrix[wordindex,itemindex]=context.get(item)
    return sparse.csr_matrix(matrix)
```

I think that a better idea would be to define the context on the left (or the right) for each word at the same time, instead of having my contextDefiner function iterate *(number of words)** times. But how to do that ? Also, I would need it to be the most efficient possible, because I have to work on a large corpus of texts.

I hope this makes sense, and that you will be able to help me !
Thank you so much. Tell me if you need anything else to understand my problem ! 
Also, the final output has to be compatible with the KMeansClustering function...

Comment: So the data structure you want to have is, if I understand you correctly, a 2-dimensional array, both dimensions of length n (vocabulary), such that each cell is incremented when encountering the word j in the context of target word i within m (n-gram size, e.g. 5) to the left and to the right. Is that so?

Comment: Yes, you're right ! However, the context is either to the left or to the right, not both at the same time (I don't know if that is what you mean).